# Testing the data file contained in a Multipart HTTP request

Tags: java, android, http, multipart, okhttp

I want to write a functionnal test that checks my android application is sending an HTTP request that contains the right file (it's a  Multipart http request)

```
public class TestClass {
    @Rule public final MockWebServer server = new MockWebServer();

    @Test
    public void testSendValuesTextJobTest() throws Exception {
        // setting up a mock response on my fake server 
        server.enqueue(new MockResponse()
                  .setResponseCode(200)

        //use android instrumentation to send the HTTP request 
        //containing a multipart file
        ...

        // Retrieve the HTTP request received by the server
        RecordedRequest request = server.takeRequest(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        String body = request.getBody().readUtf8();  // The raw http request

        // Here, I would like to retrieve the file data in the request body
        // and compare it to the source file
    }
}
```

Here is the value of body:

```
--ec7db176-a2fa-402c-84a5-7e24634be58a
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="data"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 54509

������JFIF��    [...more data...]
--ec7db176-a2fa-402c-84a5-7e24634be58a--
```

### I see two ways of doing what I want :

- Using an existing HTTP request parser to get the multipart body. Although I can't find one that accepts a String as input. (Generally it's a HttpServletRequest)
- Getting the data directly from the Buffer but I don't know how to skip the first 6 lines headers and the last one. I don't even know if I have to handle some sort of encoding.

Do you know a simple way that I could reuse in other tests ?